# Convert number to timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a number string 82014 which represents August 2014. I want to convert 82014 into the last day of August 2014 follows by time 12.00.00.000000000 AM.

So a complete conversion of '82014' to timestamp 
would look like '31-August-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM'

Comment: A number string is a varchar or something like that, right ?

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus It's actually a number datatype

Comment: While it's certainly possible to do this in Oracle, if this number comes from a client app, the client is almost always the better place to handle this kind of conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these conversions:

```
select CAST(LAST_DAY(to_timestamp('082014', 'MMYYYY')) AS TIMESTAMP) from dual;
```

If 82014 would be a number to begin with, try the following version:

```
select CAST(LAST_DAY(to_timestamp(lpad(cast(82014 as varchar2(6)), 6, '0'), 'MMYYYY')) AS TIMESTAMP) from dual
```

Comment: Hi, when I tried to replace 82014 with the column name, it gives me not a valid month. Any tips on that?

Comment: @JohnD If you got a "not a valid month" error, then the column data does not have a value that is not of the format MMYYYY. Can you list all the values / the erroring value of the column?